# AirBerlin bankruptcy and codeshare flights?

Tags: air-travel

I booked a return trip via AirBerlin before August 15th... However the 4 flights that compose the trip planned for October 27 (return on Nov 9) are operated by two other different airlines.

Do you know what could happen to my ticket? Is there a risk of cancellation?

Comment: You need to ask the airlines involved - they have significantly more info than we do.

Comment: A code share flight means Air Berlin bought some seats on another airline's flight.  Most likely those flights will operate as planned, but whether they will accept your tickets depends on Air Berlin's status at that time.

Comment: Please ask the relevant airline and, if you would, post the answer yourself. That way, you get an authoritative answer, which may be helpful to others.

Comment: Please post your exact itinerary.